# Parsing data from FamilySearch using Google Spreadsheet ImportXML

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, web-scraping

I have been trying to import different data from FamilySearch, for example:

https://www.familysearch.org/search/catalog/966883?availability=Family%20History%20Library

This website uses JavaScript to generate part of it content. 
Is there anyway to get a list of available archive documents in column under the "Note" header? Desired output would be:

Ф. 744, о. 1, д. 4 Рождения, бракосочетания, смерти 1876 (кадры 141-258)

Ф. 744, о. 1, д. 10 Рождения, бракосочетания, смерти 1877 (кадры 673-799)

Ф. 744, о. 1, д. 14 Рождения 1878 (кадры 956-970)

Ф. 744, о. 1, д. 14 (продолжение) Рождения, бракосочетания, смерти 1878 (кадры 1-118)

Ф. 744, о. 1, д. 21 Рождения, бракосочетания, смерти 1879 (кадры 818-948)

Ф. 744, о. 1, д. 27 Рождения 1880 (кадры 958-970)

Ф. 744, о. 1, д. 27 (продолжение) Рождения, бракосочетания, смерти 1880 (кадры 1-124)

... list continues till ...

Ф. 744, о. 2, д. 259 (продолжение) Рождения, бракосочетания, смерти 1918 (стр. 179-333) (страницы в беспорядке)

I tried both:

=IMPORTXML("https://www.familysearch.org/search/catalog/966883?availability=Family%20History%20Library"; "//div[@class='span4 note-header']/div")

and

=IMPORTXML("https://www.familysearch.org/search/catalog/966883?availability=Family%20History%20Library"; "//div[@class='span4 note-header']/div[@class='ng-binding']")

And of cource due to fact that website uses JavaScript I always get an error "#N/A" and when I move mouse over it, it pops out a comment "no data to import" (translated from Russian locale).

Does anybody know how to parse data from these kind of websites?

Comment: Please include a question. Also, give us an example of desired output and actual output, so we can get a better picture of what's going wrong.